# regex to match dot and number follow the dot

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to check a string in javascript if it contains **dot** followed by number (ex: **xx.12**) using regex

What is the correct regex for that.

Comment: what about this? `.+?\.(?=\d+)`, see https://regex101.com/r/gYeTJF/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try

```
let pat = /\.[0-9]/
if(pat.test(number))
{
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct regex to match your string is "xx\.12"

Backslash makes regex to take the next dot as a dot but not as anything.